# Disable screen rotation in Qt

Tags: qt, screen-rotation

Is there a simple way to disable screen rotation in Qt for whole app? I just don't want to worry about that and simply disable it.

I am using Qt 5.8 and targeting Windows.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is screen rotation an issue for a Windows app? I don't see how screen rotation would be an issue for any desktop platform? Thanks for enlightening me :-)

Comment: @Danyright It's not an issue not because of desktops not changing screen orientation, but because screen rotation appears to an application just like a resolution change would. It's mostly immaterial, in other words.

Comment: I forgot to mention it's tablet application.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to disable rotation in Windows.
The only other way I see is to display your widgets/qml rotated according to the current device orientation.
Here is a code for obtaining current orientation under Windows (tested on Windows 8.1 tablet):

```
#include <Windows.h>

enum class EOrientation
{
  Rotate_0,
  Rotate_90,
  Rotate_180,
  Rotate_270
};

EOrientation CYourViewManager::getOrientation() const
{
  DEVMODE deviceMode;

  if (!EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, 0, &deviceMode))
    return EOrientation::Rotate_0;

  switch (deviceMode.dmDisplayOrientation)
  {
    case DMDO_90:
      return EOrientation::Rotate_90;

    case DMDO_180:
      return EOrientation::Rotate_180;

    case DMDO_270:
      return EOrientation::Rotate_270;
  }

  return EOrientation::Rotate_0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pointless, because screen rotation from your perspective is the same as a screen resolution change, and if you turn *that* off, your users will be rightly hating you.

If you wish to test your code for compatibility with screen rotation, emulate it by changing screen resolution.